# How to do checkout from svn giving path as string in java

Tags: java, svn

I have a `java` code which checks out the svn path mentioned in command line. But i want to pass svn path as string as that path keeps on changing according to request.
My java code is :

```
public class DisplayFile {
List<String> fileList;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String a = "http://interactive/svn/Test/";
     String command = "svn co --username username --password password $a /home/aaa/ ";
     Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
     // Read the output
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
     String line = "";
     while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.print(line + "\n");
     }
     proc.waitFor();  
}
```

} 
Here when i give command as

```
String command = "svn co --username username --password password http://interactive/svn/Test/ /home/aaa/ ";
```

Then it works. But i dont want to give svnpath directly. Is there any way to solve this??

Comment: If you have basic knowledge in Java, you should know that it has nothing to do with "checkout from svn".  It is simply string construction that you are doing.  Please reconsider your question and title

Answer (score 1):

As SVNKit developer, I would recommend you to prefer new API based on SvnOperationFactory. The old API (based on SVNClientManager) will be operational still but all new SVN features will come only to the new API.

```
final SvnOperationFactory svnOperationFactory = new SvnOperationFactory();
try {

    final SvnCheckout checkout = svnOperationFactory.createCheckout();
    checkout.setSingleTarget(SvnTarget.fromFile(workingCopyDirectory));
    checkout.setSource(SvnTarget.fromURL(url));
    //... other options
    checkout.run();
}finally {

    svnOperationFactory.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$java DisplayFile http://interactive/svn/Test/

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

String path = args[0];
String command = "svn co --username username --password password " + path + " /home/aaa/ ";
```

Something like that?

Comment: didnt understood what ur trying to say

Comment: pass the path as a parameter in command line, then use it in the command string